# How to save woocommerce product meta data and then send it in customer email?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

After struggling for two days, am now sharing my problem here. I want to save a session value into the meta field of product when product is inserted. currently I am using this code which doesn't work

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_payment', 'save_product_status_discount', 10, 1 );

function save_product_status_discount($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email){
    $order_data = $order->get_data(); 
    $item_data = $item_obj->get_data();
    $my_post_meta1 = get_post_meta($item_data['order_id'], 'status_discount'.$item_data['order_id'], true);
     if(empty ( $my_post_meta1 )){
    update_post_meta($item_data['order_id'],'status_discount'.$item_data['order_id'],$_SESSION['status_discount_price']);

     }

}
```

Please help me what should I do. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use that, **but is not going to work well** as you should need to do it for **each order item** *(I think, the correct way is below at the end)*:

```
// Save the order meta with field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_product_status_discount', 10, 1 );
function save_product_status_discount( $order_id ) {
    $status_discount = get_post_meta($order_id, 'status_discount'.$order_id, true);
    if(empty ( $status_discount ) && ! empty( $_SESSION['status_discount_price'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'status_discount'.$order_id, $_SESSION['status_discount_price'] );
    }
}

// Display the order meta with field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_payment', 'display_product_status_discount', 10, 4 );
function save_product_status_discount($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email){
    $status_discount = get_post_meta($order_id, 'status_discount'.$order_id, true);
    if( ! empty ( $status_discount ) )
        echo '<p>'.__( 'Status discount', 'woocommerce' ) . ': ' . $status_discount . '</p>
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> **The correct way to do it,** is to incorporate this "status discount" as item ID meta data, because you can have many items in an order.

**So the best option and working code** should be simply that compact function:

```
// Save the order item meta data with custom field value and display it as order items meta data
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta','save_product_status_discount', 1, 3 );
function save_product_status_discount( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( empty( $_SESSION['status_discount_price'] ) )
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Status discount', $_SESSION['status_discount_price'], true );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested in WooCommerce 3+ and works.